# How to Display Warning message if quantity is less than 5 items

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm creating an inventory system which should display the products that needs to be restock. If the quantity of the product is only 5 it should display a message that says you need to restock now. But I don't know how to do that because I'm creating an Inventory System only and not Sales and Inventory so how should I deduct it if I don't have sales system? I'm sorry, hope u guys understand.

Here is my code:

```
public void all()
{
        SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

        MySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);

        //Clear the datatable to prevent duplicate generation of data in gridview.
        p_table.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["empinfo1"];
        m_da.Fill(p_table);
        // Clear the ListView control
        //listView3.Items.Clear();

        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                //(drow["bnum"].ToString());
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["pnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pname"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["descr"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
                //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["exp"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["qt"].ToString());

                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
    }
```

edited code:

```
public void stock()
    {

        SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

        MySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select pname from inventory where qt < 5", MySqlConnection);

        //Clear the datatable to prevent duplicate generation of data in gridview.
        p_table.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select pname from inventory where qt < 5", MySqlConnection);
        m_da.Fill(p_table);

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        StringBuilder productNames = new StringBuilder();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            productNames.Append(reader["pname"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        MySqlConnection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("There are products that needs restocking, check to restock now." + productNames);

        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                //ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["bnum"].ToString());
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["pnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pname"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["descr"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
                //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["exp"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["qt"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["interval"].ToString());

                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView4.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Thank you again. but is it really possible because I don't have sales system so there's nothing that would deduct the quantity. What I'm going to do is everytime I add a product I would put 5 as quantity.

Comment: You are welcome :), if there is no sales system in your project then there is noway of deducting products quantity. so right now it won't be useful. but if once you implement the sales system in your project (you need to deduct the quntity by 1 for every sale) then it helps you.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi sorry for disturbing again but the quantity that are less that 5 are not posting on the listview. why is that? :(

Comment: are you using my below code? which only displays the item names on messagebox

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi yes but I already added the code for them to display. I'll post the code.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I added the edited codes on my question.

Comment: check my edited answer with `solution2`

Comment: im going offline, msg me  if you still have problems so that i can solve it morning.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi it's still not posting the products for restock :(

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Even if there's no product with 5 quantity the message box still appears. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
void DisplayLowQuantityItems()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;
    Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select pname from inventory 
                                                  where qt < 5", con);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = commad.ExecuteReader();
    StringBuilder productNames= new StringBuilder();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        productNames.Append(reader["pname"].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
    }
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Following Products quantity is lessthan 5\n"+productNames);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

edited code:

```
public void stock()
    {

        MySqlConnection con;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

        con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial 
                             Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("Select pname from inventory where
                                                         qt < 5", con);

        //Clear the datatable to prevent duplicate generation of data in gridview.
        p_table.Clear();
        MySqlDataAdapter m_da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory where
                                                          qt < 5", con);
        m_da.Fill(p_table);

        MySqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

        StringBuilder productNames = new StringBuilder();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            productNames.Append(reader["pname"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("There are products that needs restocking, 
                                            check to restock now." + productNames);

        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                //ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["bnum"].ToString());
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["pnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pname"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["descr"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
                //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["exp"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["qt"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["interval"].ToString());

                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView4.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

another way of checking your data

```
    DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

    con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial 
                         Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("Select pname from inventory where
                                                     qt < 5", con);
    p_table.load(command1.ExecuteReader());
```